# STL datastructure with sorting

Tags: c++, stl

I need a data structure that could automatically sorted based on a struct.

```
struct{
  int key;
  int comparisonValue(size of the vector);
}
```

I need it in the following form:

```
datastructure<struct, vector<int>>
```

Where the data structure is automatically sorted based on the comparisonValue and based on the minimum value of the comparison value, I would like to get the vector and add some data to it.

What data structure could I use? Could I use map and is there a custom sorter for map?

What could I do if I need to modify the key, in this case the comparisonValue and still keep the order sorted?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

[std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) from the STL.

By default, this sorts key values by comparing them using `std::less<Key>`, which by default calls `operator<` on the key values.  Therefore, you can define an overload of `operator<` for your struct type::

```
bool operator<(const Key &a, const Key &b)
{
    return (a.someField < b.someField);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have implemented the method. It seems like the make_pair needs me to overload the operator== as well. Why is it so?

Comment: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/stl_function.h:203:23: error: no match for âoperator==â in â__x == __yâ
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/random.h:3360:3: note: candidate is: bool std::operator==(const std::bernoulli_distribution&, const std::bernoulli_distribution&)

Comment: @Leslieg: This shouldn't be the case.  Can you post the code you're using, along with the compiler error?

Comment: I am calling map.insert(make_pair(Key(1,0), &b)) and that causes problem. Will post a more detail one later.

Comment: I guess is because when two keys need to be pushed, it needs to compare the struct. Also, it shows that I need to overload operator() I think for getting the hash code of the struct.

Comment: undefined reference to `std::hash<Key>::operator()(Key) const'

Comment: The C++ reference page says "... Internally, the elements in a map are always sorted by its key following a specific strict weak ordering criterion... " @Oliver, are you sure the keys are all sorted?

Comment: @sonofrage: I'm not sure what you're asking. Yes, they are sorted according to operator<.

Comment: I was confused about the "strict weak ordering criterion" phrase in the reference. I tested this and found out the keys are indeed sorted when I iterate over a map. Not sure what "weak ordering" means though.

Answer (score 1):

"... and based on the minimum value of the comparison value, I would like to get the vector and add some data to it"

If what you mean is that you would like to get the smallest element in the entire collection, you might be better off with a [`std::priority_queue`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/priority_queue.html), assuming that you only ever update the smallest element.

Otherwise [`std::map`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html) is probably what you need, as Oli Charlesworth's suggests. You should probably take a look at `map`'s `lower_bound()` and `upper_bound()` methods.

You should also be aware that STL containers keep *copies* of the objects, so if you want your changes to be reflected elsewhere, you need to store pointers to the objects instead. Then you would use a separate Functor to compare the pointers according to what they point to.

Comment: What could I do if I need to modify the key, in this case the comparisonValue and still keep the order sorted?

Comment: @Leslieg: In the case of `std::map`, at least, you'd need to remove the original element, and insert a new one.